# JavaScript/Jquery best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, boolean, scoping

I've made a few functions to check form input for an ajax request. I am still getting use to JavaScript and some of these ajax requests. I am looking for any suggestions to better work with JavaScript functions, and passing variables through a function level scoping. Thank You in Advance!

Code Works as of now!
Edited!

```
//Form Handler
$("#form-submit").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({    
        beforeSend: function(){ 
            return (checkAll());
            return (passwordCheck());
        },
        complete: function(){
        },
           type: "POST",
           url: '',
           data: $("#form-submit").serialize(),
           success: function(data)
           {
           // Set Session Php Etc 
           alert('php ran');
           return true;
           }
         });
}); 

//Pushing all Input Values to an Array  
function checkAll() {
    var arr = [];
    $('#form-submit :input').each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    return (checkArray(arr));   
}

//Checks Array for empty strings 
function checkArray(arr){
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
        if (arr[i].trim() == '') {
            alert('Please Enter All Fields');   
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }   
    }
}

//Matches Password
function passwordCheck() {
    var pass1 = $('#password').val();
    var pass2 = $('#password-check').val();
    if(pass1 != pass2) {
        $('#password').addClass('highlight');
        $('#password-check').addClass('highlight');
        alert("Passwords don't match");
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#password').removeClass('highlight');
        $('#password-check').removeClass('highlight');  
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably try code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank You I will move my post in that direction :)

Comment: in `beforeSend` you can `return false` to prevent the ajax request

Comment: Notes: Use the Ajax returned promise value with `done()` and `fail()`, rather than `success` callbacks etc. Comparing boolean values to true is redundant: `if (check && password)` is more readable. Returning values from inside an Ajax callback (e.g. your `return true;`) will not do anything. Return false inside `beforeSend` to cancel the request.

Comment: Revised, I wasn't returning the functions values correctly in the beforeSend. Updating Code.